# Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, validação

como corrigir esse erro?

> Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces
> is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\POO\03 - MÉTODOS
> ESTÁTICOS\exemplo-03.php on line 64

o codigo:

```
    <?php 

    class Documento {
    
        private $numero;
    
        public function getNumero(){
            return $this->numero;
        }
    
        public function setNumero($numero){
            $resultado = Documento::validarCpf($numero);
    
            if($resultado === false){
    
                throw new Exception("CPF INFORMADO NÃO É VALIDO", 1);
    
            }
    
            $this->numero = $numero;
        }
    
        public static function validarCpf($cpf):bool{
    
            if(empty($cpf)) {
                return false;
            }
            
            $cpf = preg_match('/[0-9]/', $cpf)?$cpf:0;
    
            $cpf = str_pad($cpf, 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    
            if (strlen($cpf) != 11) {
                echo "length";
                return false;
            }
    
            else if ($cpf == '00000000000' || 
                $cpf == '11111111111' || 
                $cpf == '22222222222' || 
                $cpf == '33333333333' || 
                $cpf == '44444444444' || 
                $cpf == '55555555555' || 
                $cpf == '66666666666' || 
                $cpf == '77777777777' || 
                $cpf == '88888888888' || 
                $cpf == '99999999999') {
                return false;
    
             } else {   
                // calcula os digitos verificadores para ver se 
                // o cpf é valido
                for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {
                     
                    for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
                        $d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);  **LINHA DO ERRO**
                    }
                    $d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;
                    if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
         
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    $cpf = new Documento();
    $cpf->setNumero("123123123");
    
    var_dump($cpf->getNumero());
?>
```

Comment: *"exemplo-03.php on line 64"* e qual é a linha 64?

Comment: Provavelmente é a `$d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);`, é a unica com curly braces

Comment: editei e apontei qual a linha do erro

Comment: é essa mesmo, natan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mude as seguinte linha:

```
$d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
```

para

```
$d += $cpf[$c] * (($t + 1) - $c);
```

E a seguinte:

```
if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
```

Para:

```
if ($cpf[$c] != $d) {
```

Como a própria mensagem diz:

> ... curly braces is no longer supported
>
> traduzindo: chaves não são mais suportados

Ou seja, isso `{...}` para acessar arrays (ou até caracteres de strings) não é suportado pelo PHP8 e emite *warning* para PHP7.4:

> Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Use `[...]`, que é suportado em versões antigas também da mesma forma que o `{...}`, então **não terá problemas** de retrocompatibilidade.

- Nota sobre chaves serem obsoletos no PHP7.4 no rfc: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access
- Nota sobre chaves removido no PHP8: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.other